# How to insert and check a list inside a list of list in Java?

Tags: java, list

I have a scenario where I need to maintain a list of list and do some operation based on it. I am trying to get a list of following kind:

```
[{peter,se,red},{peter,da,red},{mark,se,red}]
```

where I first create a List to get the values and then insert this list to a list of list if it does not exist already. For instance, if {peter,se,red} comes again, it should not be inserted. Have provided the code snippet below:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();

void someFunction() {
  singleList.add("val1");
  singleList.add("val2");
  singleList.add("val3");

 if(listOfList.containsAll(singleList)) {
    <<some operation>>
 } else {
   listOfList.add(singleList);
   <<some operation>>
 }
 //clearing the list, so it can be freshly used 
 //upon successive invocation of the function
 singleList.clear();
```

Right now, the system just sticks to the else part even when I pass same list twice. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong. Also, is there another better way to implement this task?

Comment: A lot better way to implement this is to use classes instead of nested lists. In fact this is almost the worst possible way to implement this.

Comment: Use a set to remove duplicates.

Comment: How about linkedhashset? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: I think you meant to write `listOfList.contains` not containsAll

Comment: @Kayaman yeah I do not want to use this method, but I just started with this to see how my code process things.

Comment: @AlejandroC. Thanks for your suggestion, I will see how I can use linkedhashset for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet<ArrayList<String>>`, maybe that would work? Or you could use the `.contains()` method to check if the List contains the element instead of containsAll

Comment: .Contains() is working, but not in an expected way. I will see how to use HashSet for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
if(listOfList.contains(singleList)) {
    <<some operation>>
 } else {
   listOfList.add(singleList);
   <<some operation>>
 }
```

The key is that here you will be using the *contains()* method instead of the *containsAll()* method.

*containsAll(*) is checking for a collection of objects. In this case, a collection of lists and you are just supplying it a single list.